# Value property in ng-options isn't correct data type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, numbers

I have an ng-options select in my front-end application like so:

```
 <select  ng-model="calc.details.option" name="royaltyOption"
     ng-options="obj.label for obj in royaltyOptions track by obj.value">
 </select>
```

In the page's controller:

```
$scope.royaltyOptions = [{ "value": 6.25, "label": "Yes" }, { "value": 0.00, "label": "No" }];
```

The desired behavior is to send the **numeric value** to the backend once the form is submitted of either `0.00` or `6.25`. What I get instead is `NaN` - not a number. When I `console.log()` what is actually being sent back I get `[object Object]"`.

How do I get the value sent to be a number? I feel like I have followed the exact syntax mentioned in documentation and other StackOverflow/forum discussions I have found on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing object. You can use in controller. Here is something from the doc

> Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not
>   designed to work together.

You should use it like

```
ng-options="obj.label for obj in royaltyOptions track by obj.value">
```

In controller

```
console.log($scope.calc.details.option.value)
```

Comment: Wait, I actually made the change and it doesn't work... we need a ng-options expert to help I guess.

Comment: Got this nasty long error Error: [ngOptions:iexp] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/ngOptions/iexp?p0=obj.labelNaNor%obj.value%in%20royaltyOptions&p1=%3Cselect%20ng-model%3D%calc.quoteDetails.royaltyMarkup%22%20class%3D%calculator-option%form-control%20ng-pristine%20ng-valid%22%20name%3D%22greekRoyaltyMarkup%22%20ng-options%3D%obj.label%for%obj.value%in%20royaltyOptions%22%3E
    at Error (native)

Comment: "This error occurs when 'ngOptions' is passed an expression that isn't in an expected form."

Comment: @ZachCook please check now. It was my mistake. Sorry

Comment: `ng-options="obj.value as obj.label for obj in royaltyOptions track by obj.value"` change it to this real quick and I'll accept your answer, cuz it got me 99% there

Comment: @ZachCook now above snippet will work and correct way of doing that.